# Click on an 'image button' in a repeater in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, repeater, itemtemplate

I have a repeater and there is an image button in each row of this.

By clicking on each Image button ,I should get the Id of respective row but I don't Know how to manage the click  event of this image button in repeater.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

*ASPX*

```
<asp:LinkButton OnCommand="lbRemove_Command" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Key")%>' CommandName="Remove" runat="server">
```

*Code Behind*

```
protected void lbRemove_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.CommandName)
    {
        case "Remove":
            string ca = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, he meant ImageButton.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [**ItemCommand**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcommand.aspx) event of repeater. You may also look in to [**ItemDataBound**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx) for custom actions on while binding data source.